# replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0 (updating facebook status fail)

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I'm trying to to make a little app to post on myfacebookwall. but the status isn't updated.the strange thing is that the log cat error shows like if the id of the mail that the cell phone uses to connect to facebook where replaced by the gmail, but the app doesn't crash.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

The code is this:

```
package com.ketanoexample.facebooktrial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class fbshare extends Activity  {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("425034397547522");
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bshare_layout);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfb);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            compartirconfb();
        }
    });

}



public void updateStatus(String accessToken){
    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", "test status update made by gezn-Automated response app social handler");
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");
        showToast("Update process complete. Respose:"+response);
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void compartirconfb() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*
     * Get existing access_token if any
     */
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

    facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
            editor.commit();
            updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}   
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

The log cat is this, note I enabled log true, on Util.java of the facebook SDK, because I couldn't see the error before.

```
07-26 18:44:34.399: D/dalvikvm(5676): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 45% free 3765K/6727K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+6ms
07-26 18:44:43.049: D/dalvikvm(5676): GC_EXPLICIT freed 85K, 46% free 3680K/6727K, external 0K/0K, paused 83ms
07-26 18:44:54.339: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys
07-26 18:44:54.339: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED - Disconnect event - remove keys]
07-26 18:44:54.339: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): New network state is DISCONNECTED
07-26 18:44:54.349: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:54.349: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=0 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:54.349: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: COMPLETED ==> DISCONNECTED
07-26 18:44:54.439: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:54.439: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=2 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:54.439: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: DISCONNECTED ==> SCANNING
07-26 18:44:54.909: D/wifi(1428): wifi doCommand: ret=-1
07-26 18:44:55.669: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): Trying to associate with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 (SSID='kawsaytaraj' freq=2432 MHz)
07-26 18:44:55.669: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=3 BSSID=00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2
07-26 18:44:55.679: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [Trying to associate with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 (SSID='kawsaytaraj' freq=2432 MHz)]
07-26 18:44:55.689: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=3 BSSID=00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2]
07-26 18:44:55.689: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: SCANNING ==> ASSOCIATING
07-26 18:44:56.279: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=4 BSSID=00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2
07-26 18:44:56.279: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=4 BSSID=00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2]
07-26 18:44:56.279: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATING ==> ASSOCIATED
07-26 18:44:56.289: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): Associated with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2
07-26 18:44:56.289: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [Associated with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2]
07-26 18:44:56.299: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:56.299: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:56.309: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: ASSOCIATED ==> FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE
07-26 18:44:56.350: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:56.350: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:56.359: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE ==> FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE
07-26 18:44:56.359: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=6 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:56.359: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=6 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE ==> GROUP_HANDSHAKE
07-26 18:44:56.369: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]]
07-26 18:44:56.369: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=7 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=12 state=7 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00]
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): Changing supplicant state: GROUP_HANDSHAKE ==> COMPLETED
07-26 18:44:56.369: I/wpa_supplicant(1551): CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 completed (reauth) [id=12 id_str=]
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiMonitor(1428): Event [CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2 completed (reauth) [id=12 id_str=]]
07-26 18:44:56.369: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): New network state is CONNECTED
07-26 18:44:56.379: D/WifiStateTracker(1428): Reset connections and stopping DHCP
07-26 18:44:56.399: W/Smack/Packet(1582): notify conn break (IOEx), close connection
07-26 18:44:56.399: D/Smack(1582): [XMPPConn] close connection, notifyClosed=false
07-26 18:44:56.429: D/dhcpcd(6058): received SIGTERM, stopping
07-26 18:44:56.429: D/dhcpcd(6058): deleting route 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.0.1
07-26 18:44:56.429: D/dhcpcd(6058): deleting IP address 192.168.0.102/24
07-26 18:44:56.429: D/dhcpcd(6058): executing `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks', reason STOP
07-26 18:44:56.559: D/GTalkService(1582): [GTalkConnection.21] connectionClosed: connId=22690, error=CONNECTION FAILED
07-26 18:44:57.439: D/WifiStateTracker(1428): DHCP request started
07-26 18:44:57.449: D/dhcpcd(6119): dhcpcd 4.0.15 starting
07-26 18:44:57.449: D/dhcpcd(6119): hardware address = 58:17:0c:43:74:29
07-26 18:44:57.449: D/dhcpcd(6119): executing `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks', reason PREINIT
07-26 18:44:57.469: D/dhcpcd(6119): host does not support a monotonic clock - timing can skew
07-26 18:44:57.469: D/dhcpcd(6119): broadcasting for a lease
07-26 18:44:57.479: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending DHCP_DISCOVER with xid 0x1c3d4b6a, next in 4.55 seconds
07-26 18:44:57.479: D/dhcpcd(6119): offered 192.168.0.102 from 192.168.0.1
07-26 18:44:57.479: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending DHCP_REQUEST with xid 0x1c3d4b6a, next in 4.76 seconds
07-26 18:44:57.489: D/dhcpcd(6119): acknowledged 192.168.0.102 from 192.168.0.1
07-26 18:44:57.489: D/dhcpcd(6119): checking 192.168.0.102 is available on attached networks
07-26 18:44:57.489: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending ARP probe (1 of 3), next in 1.54 seconds
07-26 18:44:59.039: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending ARP probe (2 of 3), next in 1.47 seconds
07-26 18:44:59.379: W/WifiStateTracker(1428): Skip RssiApprox, not connected...
07-26 18:45:00.516: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending ARP probe (3 of 3), next in 2.00 seconds
07-26 18:45:02.379: W/WifiStateTracker(1428): Skip RssiApprox, not connected...
07-26 18:45:02.516: D/dhcpcd(6119): leased 192.168.0.102 for 7200 seconds
07-26 18:45:02.516: D/dhcpcd(6119): adding IP address 192.168.0.102/24
07-26 18:45:02.519: D/dhcpcd(6119): adding route to 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.0.1
07-26 18:45:02.519: D/dhcpcd(6119): executing `/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks', reason BOUND
07-26 18:45:03.443: D/WifiStateTracker(1428): DHCP succeeded with lease: 7200
07-26 18:45:03.449: V/WifiStateTracker(1428): IP configuration: ipaddr 192.168.0.102 gateway 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 200.87.100.10 dns2 200.87.100.40 DHCP server 192.168.0.1 lease 7200 seconds
07-26 18:45:03.509: D/WifiWatchdogService(1428): (android.server.ServerThread) kawsaytaraj (00:23:cd:1c:b7:e2) does not require the watchdog
07-26 18:45:03.519: D/GTalkService(1582): ##### Network broadcast (connected=true) type=WIFI, state=CONNECTED
07-26 18:45:03.519: D/GTalkService(1582): [GTalkConnection.1] setInternalNetworkState: type=1, state=CONNECTED
07-26 18:45:03.529: D/CMStats(5741): CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: noConnectivity = false
07-26 18:45:03.529: D/CMStats(5741): CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: starting service
07-26 18:45:03.559: D/CMStats(5741): User has not opted in -- skipping reporting.
07-26 18:45:03.589: D/Tethering(1428): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
07-26 18:45:03.639: I/MediaUploader(5758): No need to wake up
07-26 18:45:04.573: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending ARP announce (1 of 2), next in 2.00 seconds
07-26 18:45:05.049: D/dalvikvm(1582): GC_CONCURRENT freed 372K, 44% free 3827K/6791K, external 0K/512K, paused 5ms+10ms
07-26 18:45:06.580: D/dhcpcd(6119): sending ARP announce (2 of 2)
07-26 18:45:06.580: D/dhcpcd(6119): renew in 3596 seconds
07-26 18:45:06.859: D/GTalkService(1582): [RosterListenerImpl] removeTalkPresence for account=1, deleted=18
07-26 18:45:06.869: D/GTalkService(1582): [ContactPresence] removeAllContactsPresence: account=1, set null presence for 4
07-26 18:45:07.379: D/GTalkService(1582): [RosterMgr] roster not modified
07-26 18:45:07.409: E/TalkProvider(1582): replaceContactWithContactId: contactId==0!!! pedro.gezn@gmail.com, acct=1
07-26 18:45:07.409: E/TalkProvider(1582): insert presence failed for account=1 username=pedro.gezn@gmail.com client_type=0 status= cap=8 priority=0 mode=3
07-26 18:45:07.439: D/GTalkService(1582): [OtrMgr] OTR not modified
```